# js function to go back in browser history to last browsed page of specific domain?

Tags: javascript, cross-domain, webbrowser-control, browser-history

I need the js function to go back in history to the last pages used in a specific domain.

reason: I send people to a subdomain to see specific content-galleries (gallery.mydomain.xyz/#1etc). I need them to return to the last page where they left of from the specific tld (mydomain.xyz/pageX) after having clicked through a number of images/videos there at subdomain...

is this possible? any ideas?
thx!

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible using the built-in browser history, no, because your access to that from JavaScript is close to non-existent.

What you can do instead is save the location you want to take them back to in, say, session storage (use local storage instead if this is in a different window), and then link back to that page.

More about session storage / local storage in the [web storage spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/webstorage/), but the short version is that it stores strings in a storage area specific to your origin, so for instance:

```
localStorage.setItem("last-location", "foo");
```

...stores `"foo"` in local storage for your origin, with the key `"last-location"`. You can then use `getItem` to get it later when you need it:

```
var lastLocation = localStorage.getItem("last-location");
```

Comment: It's also possible to [share local storage between domains](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33957477/cross-domain-localstorage-with-javascript), in order to access the location from another domain.

Comment: @AndersonGreen - Not really. It's possible to do *messaging* cross-domain with [`postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage), and of course if you have a page open in each domain, they each have access to their own local storage and can use that information when messaging each other. That's not shared local storage, it's messaging.

Answer (score 0):

you could use a simple get/post variable to tell where the user is coming from and store that in a session variable for later use when the user is to be returned. As far as I know you cant access the users browsing history from the browsing client with Javascript as its a violation of the sandbox design but that may have changed recently

Answer (score 0):

thx both of you for the quick answer!
... I kind of see, not being a versatile coder myself. but I get the problem involved. and see session-storage is where I want to look at then...

I will have to make this a coding job given my non-skills here :-}

but now I know what to ask for. thx again.